# What does "their" indicate?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Her features were those of a woman about fifty, who had once been
>   handsome. Sorrow and weeping had left traces upon **them** which not
>   time itself would ever have produced without **their** aid; her face
>   was deadly pale; and there was a nervous contortion of the lip, and an
>   unnatural fire in her eye, which showed too plainly that her bodily
>   and mental powers had nearly sunk, beneath an accumulation of misery.

I think "them" indicate her features.
What does "their" indicate?

source [THE BLACK VEIL](http://www.ibiblio.org/ebooks/Dickens/Dickens_Veil.pdf#search=%27The+Black+Veil+by+Charles+Dickens+full%27)

Answer (score 3):

"Their" refers to "Sorrow and weeping".

Answer (score 0):

@ParaDice is right, but I thought I'd add a bit of a breakdown of the logic needed to arrive at that conclusion.

I'll break your passage up a bit

> Her features were those of a woman about fifty, who had once been handsome.

The woman being described looks about 50 years old, it's clear that she was once good looking (implying that her looks have faded somewhat)

> Sorrow and weeping had left traces upon them

Them here refers to a recent plural which has been marked. The lady's features fit the bill.

> which not time itself would ever have produced without their aid;

Something has marked the features of her face. Time is the greatest enemy of youthful looks, but even time could not have done alone what has been done without help from something, again plural.

Sorrow and weeping fit here

There are rules of sentences which dictate which entity articles refer to, but if I'm honest, the above is how I, an English native, actually figure out what's going on in tortuous passages like the example. Hope this helps.